# Complete characteristic p perfect Tate rings are uniform?

Tags: nt.number-theory, p-adic-analysis, rigid-analytic-geometry, p-adic-hodge-theory

In Lemma 7.1.6 of his lecture notes on perfectoid spaces, Bhatt states that every complete characteristic p perfect Tate ring $A$ is uniform. In the proof he uses the Banach open mapping theorem on the Frobenius.

My problem is that the Frobenius is not a  $A$-linear map and so all forms of Banach open mapping theorems that I am aware of do not apply (the closest related one that I am aware of is Theorem 6.16 in Wedhorn's notes on adic spaces).

Does anyone know a Banach open mapping theorem that applies here? Or can one prove that the inverse of Frobenius is bounded via other means? I would also be happy about a proof for $K$-Banach algebras because this is all I care about.

Comment: Can't you consider the target of the Frobenius (i.e., $A$) as an $A$-module via the Frobenius map? Then the map in question will become $A$-linear. You will lose the finite generation of the target as an $A$-module, but Theorem 0.1 from https://arxiv.org/abs/1407.5647v2 should still apply and give the claim.

Comment: Great, thanks, I wasn't aware of that trick.